# C++ Eclipse Luna CDT - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

UPDATE:

It seems it's only my Event_Creator project that has this problem. All my other projects can be compiled and run successfully.

---

Update 2:

When I want to build my project, I can only choose from "default" build, normally I should see debug and release. So I guess something is wrong with my build settings for the project?

---

I have a problem with eclipse luna, whenever I try to build my project I get this error:

> Errors occurred during the build.
>       Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Event_Creator'.
>       Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>       Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
>       java.lang.NullPointerException

Event_Creator being my program then.

I have no idea what's causing this really, I've been programming on this program for about 2 weeks and I've been able to compile it just fine, but today this just happened.

I tried a bunch of things, even removed eclipse then re-downloaded it. I also tried creating new workspaces to see if there was something wrong with my current one, but I still had the same problem.

I'm using C/C++ workspace as well, so I'm afaik I'm not using some weird java workspace that could mess with me.

I'm using minGw compiler and this CDT repository:

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.6/

And a reminder, I've been able to compile just fine for two weeks, this just happened today when I started my computer and opened eclipse.

Inside my .log file in \Eclipse\Workspaces.metadata i found these entries that was related to the nullpointer error, though I have no idea what they mean really.

```
!SESSION 2015-05-05 12:25:46.074 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-05 12:26:24.835
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-05-05 12:26:24.853
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\Gustav'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2015-05-05 12:26:30.095
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    ... 17 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 0 2015-05-05 12:26:30.098
!MESSAGE Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 0 2015-05-05 12:26:30.098
!MESSAGE Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 75 2015-05-05 12:26:30.102
!MESSAGE Errors occurred during the build.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 75 2015-05-05 12:26:30.102
!MESSAGE Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Event_Creator'.
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    ... 17 more
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 0 2015-05-05 12:26:30.102
!MESSAGE Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 4 0 2015-05-05 12:26:30.102
!MESSAGE Internal error building project Event_Creator configuration Default
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path.append(Path.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.addOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.calculateOutputs(BuildDescription.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.handleMultiSteps(BuildDescription.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.initDescription(BuildDescription.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.BuildDescription.init(BuildDescription.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.buildmodel.DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.createBuildDescription(DefaultBuildDescriptionFactory.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.buildmodel.BuildDescriptionManager.createBuildDescription(BuildDescriptionManager.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.InternalBuildRunner.invokeBuild(InternalBuildRunner.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:753)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.build(CommonBuilder.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.buildInternal(Workspace.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.build(Workspace.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.BuildAction$1.runInWorkspace(BuildAction.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

from .bak_0.log (if it's important as well)

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.ui 4 0 2015-05-05 11:52:25.492
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.linuxtools.valgrind.ui [281]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Udpdated my question so it contains .log output. But I really don't have any idea what most of it means.

Comment: I just saw that for some reason when I want to build I can only choose "default", normally I should see "debug" and "release". Don't know what causes this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, since I noticed that Event_Creator project only have "default" build option while my other projects (that I could build) had "debug" and "release" option, I just created a new empty project and manually moved my files into that project, then I opened eclipse, refreshed my new project and voilà, I could build it.

I'm assuming something happened to a project file in the old directory that corrupted my build.